# Python: Referring to single labels in a Pmw RadioSelect

Tags: python, tkinter, pmw

I would like to create a hover box (or info box) which opens up when the user places the mouse cursor on top of a Pmw RadioSelect *label*. For example, when the cursor is placed on top of "Primary" the program opens an info box explaining what "Primary" means.

[image: Pic 1, Pmw RadioSelect]

Problem: I don't know how to access the individual labels *inside* the RadioSelect object. I need to bind a method to the individual labels, but I don't know how to refer to them.

Extra: How could I have solved this myself? I tried looking at the RadioSelect attributes with dir() and I read the Pmw manual online, but couldn't find the information.

**EDIT** This is what I have found out thus far: The [manual](http://pmw.sourceforge.net/doc/RadioSelect.html) says that the labels only start to exist if their position is set explicitly:

> **labelpos**
>
> Initialisation option. Specifies where to place the label component.
>
> If **None**, a label component is not created. The default is **None**

After setting it explicitly for example as so:

```
self.rs = Pmw.RadioSelect(parent, labelpos = 'w')
```

you can refer to it with
self.rs.component('label')

But I still don't know how to reach the individual labels.

**EDIT 2:** The trick was just to assign the RadioSelect "items" into variables like the accepted answer suggests:

```
self.cb1 = self.radio_select.add("text")
```

After assigning the "item" into a variable you can simply bind methods to the variable, like such:

```
self.balloon = Pmw.Balloon(self, initwait=500, relmouse='both')
self.balloon.bind(self.cb1, "Balloon text example")
```

Comment: I am back. What do you mean by: *But I still don't know how to reach the individual labels*? I ask this because I believe you already answered this question in `self.rs.component('label')`, so ...?

Comment: Hi again Billal! I hope my question has not vague. By reaching the individual labels I meant this: `self.balloon.bind(self.cb1, "balloon text")`. I was trying to find a way to have a reference - like **self.cb1** in your answer - to be able to bind a method to it. Now I feel silly when I saw that I could just have assigned a variable like you did in your answer: `self.cb1 = self.checkbuttons.add('Primary')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well your problem, I think you are looking for:

1. To rely on Pmw to draw the widgets (unlike what I did with Tkinter previously)
2. *when the cursor is placed on top of "Primary" the program opens an info box explaining what "Primary" means.* (the effect I produced on the demo below)
3. Identify individual checkbuttons (or what you call in your own terms reaching  the *individual labels* within the `Pmw.RadioSelect`)

## Solution:

1. The solution for the first problem you know it already.
2. For the second problem, as I explained previously, you will need to instantiate  `Pmw.Balloon()` and bind it to individual checkbuttons (or *labels* as you call them). I re-programmed that as you can see below but using an other method. I mean I relied mainly on [`add()`](http://pmw.sourceforge.net/doc/RadioSelect.html) which  *returns the component widget.* Then I binded the instance of `Pmw.Balloon()` to the returned value from `add()`. Doing this, you already offer yourself a way to access individually the checkbuttons (and you play more with this if you want)
3. You can access individual checkbuttons (*labels*) by using [`getvalue()`](http://pmw.sourceforge.net/doc/RadioSelect.html) or [`getcurselection()`](http://pmw.sourceforge.net/doc/RadioSelect.html) methods which work similarly by returning the  return the name of the currently selected button. **But** in practice, you will get tuples ( I mean these functions return the names of all selected checkbuttons, as I showed in the `access_to_labels_individually()` that I used as a callback method to display the names of the checkbuttons you select; of course you can play with that also depending on your needs)

## Code

Here is an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) program:

```
'''
Created on Jun 18, 2016

@author: Billal BEGUERADJ
'''
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import Pmw
import tkinter as tk

class Begueradj:
   def __init__(self, parent):

       self.balloon = Pmw.Balloon(parent) 

       # Create and pack a vertical RadioSelect widget, with checkbuttons.
       self.checkbuttons = Pmw.RadioSelect(parent,
           buttontype = 'checkbutton',
           orient = 'vertical',
           labelpos = 'w',
           command = self.access_to_labels_individually,
           hull_borderwidth = 2,
           hull_relief = 'ridge',
        )
       self.checkbuttons.pack(side = 'left', expand = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)

       # Add some buttons to the checkbutton RadioSelect        
       self.cb1 = self.checkbuttons.add('Primary')
       self.cb2 = self.checkbuttons.add('Secondary')
       self.cb3 = self.checkbuttons.add('Tertiary')
       # Bind the Balloon instance to each widget
       self.balloon.bind(self.cb1, 'Primary:\n This is our primary service')
       self.balloon.bind(self.cb2, 'Secondary:\n This is our primary service')
       self.balloon.bind(self.cb3, 'Tertiary:\n This is our primary service')  



   # You can use getvalue() or getcurselection() to access individual labels    
   def access_to_labels_individually(self, tag, state):
       print(self.checkbuttons.getvalue())            


# Main program starts here   
if __name__ =='__main__':
   begueradj = Pmw.initialise(fontScheme = 'pmw1')
   begueradj.title('Billal BEGUERADJ')
   d = Begueradj(begueradj)
   begueradj.mainloop()
```

## Demo

(I am keeping the same screenshots because the above program produces the same results)

Here are screenshots of the running program related to the mouse hovering over each `tkinter.Checkbutton()` instance whether it is selected or not:

[image: Checkbutton 1]

[image: Checkbutton 2]

[image: Checkbutton 3]

Comment: I appreciate you effort and like the idea of using Pmw Balloons. I think I will apply it in my program later on. 
However, your reply doesn't answer my question. The question was how to access or refer to individual labels inside a Pmw RadioSelect. I upwoted your answer, but will wait if someone has a direct answer to the question.

Comment: Moro. So if I understood your edit, you are looking to access to *Primary*? And  the checkbuttons you are looking for must be drawn using `Pmw.RadioSelect()` unlike what I did? If this is the case then you can use `getcurselection()` or `getvalue()` methods. If you do not understand from the manual how these 2 methods work I can provide you a  code sample. @Crebit

Comment: I re-coded the program according to what you said.  But when I finished, I guess I misunderstood (again) what you meant by *labels*. I will continue the solution after I come back. Please let me know if that is what you are looking for or not.  @Crebit

Comment: I accepted the answer now that you changed the code. I didn't have difficulties with getting the values in the RadioSelect. Rather, I didn't know how to bind methods to the "text" parts of the RadioSelect. But by assigning them to variables when adding them ( `self.cb1 = self.checkbuttons.add('Primary')`) I was later able to refer to them and bind methods to them. Thanks for your enthusiasm and thorough answer!